# Trigger Error with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing something simple. Basically everytime a user register themself into the system, a trigger should run and copy the row which contain the ID and insert it into another table called userinfo.

Theres two table. One only contain username id and password, and another one contains foreign key linking the users.UserID and userinfo.UserID. I wish to insert new user to userinfo everytime users table is updated with new member. However the trigger keeps giving me error. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I'm open for any easier/proper way too. This is my first time playing with trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewUsers_Trigger AFTER insert ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN INSERT INTO `pms`.`userinfo` (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`,
`Address`, `City`, `Country`, `PostCode`, `PhoneNumber`) VALUES ('2',
'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'); END
```

Comment: add one like at the top as `delimiter //` and after the `END` add `//` and last line `delimiter ;`

Comment: I'm sorry @AbhikChakraborty I dont really get you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are missing the delimiter http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html check the example of `amount < 0 `

Comment: Please post the error message you receive.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that fixed the trigger . however it seems my trigger code itself is wrong. Now everytime I create a new user, the trigger refuse to work and disable the registration. Mind having a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger needs delimiter to be set, also you mentioned that there is a foreign key so the trigger should look like

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER NewUsers_Trigger AFTER insert ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO `pms`.`userinfo` (`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`,
         `Address`, `City`, `Country`, `PostCode`, `PhoneNumber`) VALUES (new.UserID,
          'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'); 
END; //
delimiter ;
```

Note I have removed 2 with new.UserID which is the last inserted id from the user table so that same id is inserted to the other table and there is no error raised on foreign key constraints

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot man. My mistake, i totally forgot to change that back , was trying to see if the Insert Into syntax was correct at first. :)